# Imported Spring MVC @Controller not available in maven test or provided scopes

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, maven-2

I wanted to speed up my automated acceptance testing of an API, and the best way I found to do it was to create an API endpoint that allowed the automated acceptance tests to wipe my database after each test run. This has given me dramatic performance improvements compared with other techniques.

However, it seems like a bad idea to ship my API with an endpoint allowing the entire contents of the database to be deleted. Even if I secure the endpoint, it still seems like a bad idea.

So.. to avoid shipping the delete endpoint, I included the @Controller with the delete endpoint into its own maven module, and then tried including that maven module in my API using maven's 'test' scope (and then 'provided' scope when that didn't work). Unfortunately, the controller with the delete logic does not seem to be found if I am using 'test' or 'provided' scope. It is found when I import with the default scope (or no scope explicitly set).

What am I missing? Why doesn't what I'm trying work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Spring profiles. Annotate your controller with the `@Profile` annotation:

```
@Controller
@Profile("acceptance")
public class SpecialController {
    @RequestMapping("/stuff")
    public void doDangerousStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, if you use run the application for your acceptance tests using the property `spring.profiles.active`, you can control if this bean should be loaded or not.

I have no idea how you start your application, but if you use `mvn spring-boot:run`, you could use:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=acceptance
```

Nonetheless, I find your use case a bit strange, because if you use **spring-boot-starter-test** you already can write JUnit tests and autowire beans from the application within your tests, so you could autowire your repositories/DAO and wipe the data directly in stead of exposing it through an API.

Comment: You're right re "you could autowire your repositories/DAO and wipe the data directly in stead of exposing it through an API", much better option. Because these tests are BDD calling REST endpoints, it didn't cross my mind I could simply autowire my bean. Still the bean is not found if I'm using test or provided scope... not sure why....